# Webform doesn't send hidden input if sender is not logged-in

Tags: webforms

I have a webform which works fine only it is submitted for logged in users.

The problem is that the webform includes a hidden input. When I receive the email (sent by the webform) I can see all the values for the inputs, but the hidden input value is missing.

This does not happens if the webform is submitted for a logged in user.

Is this something related to permissions?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give us the token you use for the hidden field? Maybe the token you use only available for logged user. I used hidden fields but with a general token (for example date or ip_adress) and it works fine for non logged users

Comment: I used the token get[q].

Comment: you mean %get[q]?right?I used it and it works for me..what version of webform do you use?I have version 3.14

Comment: thanks Mika, I change the input to 'text' and then I hide it using css. Not the best but I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was using the direct input instead try using the token for raw input. That can help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm way late to the party, but I don't think the problem has anything to do with your user's status. It's a quirk in the Webform module itself. It [doesn't store hidden values in the server-side cache](https://drupal.org/node/1580700).

That issue queue discussion has a fix to $form_state that apparently works. I'm going to give it a whirl.

I think switching from "Secure value" to "Hidden element" (down at the bottom of the field settings) as making it a regular field and hiding it with CSS. But I could be wrong.